# The logic behind the generated ID values from controls on storyboard files/NIB files

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-generation

I'm creating a code generator for Xcode code and it's interface markup

I notice that the "ID" xml attribute from UI controls has some scrambled value, I was wondering what is the logic generating this info.

would it be just a apple approach to make it harder to create self generated code?
would I be able to make my generated app work with my-own-whatever-IDvalue setup?

I'm developing it anyway with any value and it is working fine so far, but not sure when it gets more complex

Comment: what "scrambled value" are you referring to, can you cutnpaste few samples? Hows the project coming along?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I'm trying to figure it out myself. It seems that the only files that keep a record of the id is the storyboard file itself.

Answer (score 2):

edwin, mine is an examination only, and from having tried to tweak the .storyboard/.nib code in the past, and having had to match up these ids, i think the only things that are critical are that:

1. the ids can contain "0-9" "A-Z" "a-z" and dashes ('-')
2. they must be unique and cannot conflict with other ids within the same xml
3. they must match in declaration and identifier
4. ids for storyboard scenes and for controllers seem to be numeric, starting at the top of the file and ascending
5. ids for views seem to consist of a triple of the form xxx-xx-xxx

if you stick with that, and especially if you don't expect to then tweak the generated files, you should be safe.  even if you do expect to tweak the files, Xcode should honor those ids you've generated as long as they're unique.  i just don't know what would happen if you then add a view that creates an id that conflicts with one you've generated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by numeric and ascending ? If I wanted to generate them in ascending order, how would i do that ?

Answer (score -1):

Does anyone have a definitive answer on how these identities are created?  "orR-Rm-srM" appears to be a base-62 number with each digit being a-zA-Z0-9.  I've heard comments that the identity is a randomly generated value, but I have a hard time believing that since it would require unnecessary lookup tables during compilation.

Tom